# QUnit test ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I know there are already lots of posts out there covering this, but I'm not that good at Javascript at baseline, and most of the ones that should probably make sense use an older syntax that is confusing me.

Here is my function that I want to work:

```
function getUpdateForm() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test_response.html',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#Form_div").html(data);
    },
  });
};
```

This is my response file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Response</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my QUnit test:

```
QUnit.test('getUpdateForm ajax request', function(assert) {

  $.ajax = function(request) {
    assert.equal(
      request.url,
      'test_response.html',
      'request url is correct'
    );
    assert.equal(request.type, 'GET',
      'request type is correct'
    );
    assert.equal(request.dataType, 'json',
      'request dataType is correct'
    );
  };

  getUpdateForm();

  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.equal($("#Form_div").html(), '',// not exactly sure what to put
      'Received correct html in response'
    );
    assert.async();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Currently it doesn't even attempt to run the `assert.equal` in the `setTimeout` function.

Please give as many details details as possible, and I will probably have many questions. First one being, how does test even get the correct function from `$.ajax = function(request)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do... but there is a [tool to mock out Ajax requests](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/) for just this purpose! (Which I am the maintainer of, but still...)

Basically, in your test (or a [`beforeEach` hook](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit/module)) you create a mock based on your real Ajax call, then do your code test.

First, I would start by adding a callback in your source code function so we know when the ajax call is done in the test:

```
function getUpdateForm(doneFunction) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test_response.html',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#Form_div").html(data);
    },
    complete: doneFunction   // <-- this is new!
  });
};
```

Now set up your test with a mock, and execute assertions...

```
QUnit.test('getUpdateForm ajax request', function(assert) {
  let done = assert.async(); // set up an async test

  $.mockjax({
    url: "test_response.html",
    responseText: "<h1>Test Page</h1>"
  });

  getUpdateForm(function() {  // this is our callback function
    // now do your assertions on the content in the form div...
    assert.equal($("#Form_div h1").text(), 'Test Page', 'Received correct title in html response');

    done(); // then tell QUnit you are done testing.
  });
});
```

Don't forget to include the Mockjax JS file *in addition to* the QUnit JS file!

Comment: Took me a little to figure it out, but thanks. Any chance you could help me on this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026849/qunit-test-for-change-event-by-entering-text-in-text-input/54027412#54027412)